# ReleaseDate data not persisting in Edit View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I have the following Index view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCMovie3.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<form asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index">
    <p>
        Title: <input type="text" name="SearchString">
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </th>        
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

And here is the "Edit" view listed in the Index view:

```
@model MVCMovie3.Models.Movie

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<form asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Movie</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Genre" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Genre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Genre" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Price" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Rating" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Rating" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Rating" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ReleaseDate" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Title" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

My problem is that everything shows fine on the Index view but when I click the link to bring up the Edit view the release date is gone. Any suggestions?
Also, here is my model that I generated the views off of:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MVCMovie3.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "ReleaseDate")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In playing around with it I've found that if I take off the `[Display(Name`....  and `[DisplayType`....  parts then it runs fine, except now my release date is  not in the format I want it to be in. Help please.....

Comment: What do you mean by Released date gone?

Comment: if you look at the index view it shows the release date that was entered for the record but when you click on the edit link the release date is replaced with "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: `[Display]` has nothing to do with it (that's only used when generating the label - in your case its the same as the property name so its a bit pointless). `[DataType]` means you generate `type="date"` which generates your browsers HTML-5 datepicker and if thats the case you need to use the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute.

Comment: I need to keep the 
[Display(Name = "Release Date")] 
and the
 [DataType(DataType.date)]
in the model to make it so the Release Date shows in the correct format in the index view, which works. The problem is when I click on one of the "Edit" links the text next to the Release Date box is literally "mm/dd/yyyy" and not the date that should be in there.

Answer (score 0):

For now the only fix that i have found is to change the following code:

```
[Display(Name = "Release Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

To:

```
[Display(Name = "Release Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

This is, to remove the `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` from the `DisplayFormat` line.

No the less as i mentioned before this would make the `DatePicker` field to show a date format in the form `dd-MM-yyyy` (the default one) and not the one you selected.